# Problemas com o file_put_contents()

Tags: php, file-put-contents

Tenho um script que roda toda vez que determinada página é carregada.

Basicamente, ele faz uma busca no banco e salva os valores em um arquivo:

```
$servicos = $db->prepare('SELECT id_servico, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(data) dia, user, cliente, situacao FROM servicos);
$servicos->execute(array());
$servicos_result = $servicos->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$out = array();
foreach($servicos_result as $row) {
    $out[] = array(
        'id' => $row->id_servico,
        'user' => $row->loja,
        'cliente' => $row->cliente,
        'situacao' => $row->situacao,
        'start' => $row->dia . '000',
        'end' => $row->dia . '000'
    );
}

$stringData = json_encode(array('success' => 1, 'result' => $out));
file_put_contents ( "events.json.php" , $stringData );
```

O problema é que tem demorado um pouco para que o arquivo seja atualizado após alguma alteração no banco. Ou seja: ele não é atualizado na primeira vez que a página é reccaregada, mas só após alguns minutos e tentativas.

O arquivo está com cerca de 400kb.

Isso pode ser alguma limitação do servidor?

Comment: Permissão de gravação no diretório?

Comment: @ShutUpMagda. O arquivo tem permissão 666. As informações são salvas, mas demora muito.

Comment: Qual o tempo de conclusão da consulta em si?

Comment: @ismael Pelo Workbench está sendo em 0.078 sec / 0.282 sec

Comment: @marcelo2605 apaguei meus comments anteriores pra não deixar bagunça embaixo da sua pergunta, como já está resolvido. Qualquer nova dúvida, abra uma pergunta, ou se tiver duvidas sobre esta aqui, deixe um comment na resposta que eu retorno se estiver online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caso não precise realmente fazer um cache em disco, é muito mais fácil usar um echo simples, e gravar o próprio arquivo como  `events.json.php` :

```
$servicos = $db->prepare('SELECT id_servico, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(data) dia, user, cliente, situacao FROM servicos);
$servicos->execute(array());
$servicos_result = $servicos->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$out = array();
foreach($servicos_result as $row) {
    $out[] = array(
        'id' => $row->id_servico,
        'user' => $row->loja,
        'cliente' => $row->cliente,
        'situacao' => $row->situacao,
        'start' => $row->dia . '000',
        'end' => $row->dia . '000'
    );
}

echo json_encode(array('success' => 1, 'result' => $out));
```

Faria sentido você gravar em arquivo se fosse uma aplicação muitíssimo acessada, e pouco alterada, mas para volumes menores de acesso, ou maiores de alteração, servir o dado diretamente do DB não é um problema.

Mas note que se usar essa estratégia no futuro, de salvar em DB, evite a extensão `.php`, senão vai passar pelo parser do PHP à toa.

No seu caso, aparentemente a demora estava no cache do browser, e não na gravação do arquivo. Uma solução seria configurar uma pasta no servidor Web com uma regra de cache completamente diferente, mas se a solução acima bastar, é muito mais prático.